# Проверка на нажатия QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть вектор: `static QVector<QString> pages = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};`

Нужно чтобы при каждой нажатии `QPushButton` в `textBrowser` выводилось по одному элементу вектора.

```
void theory::on_next_page_clicked()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size())
    {
        ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(pages[i] + " ");
        if (//проверка на клик)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Так как вы написали, работать не будет-вы нарушаете идеологию, заложенную в термин "событийно управляемое приложение".

Вам нужно при каждом клике (это и есть "событие") проверять, не вышел ли индекс за границу массива, если вышел - обнулять, после чего выводить элемент, соответствующий этому индексу.

Ну а текущий индекс нужно сделать полем класса вашего окна и помнить между вызовами слота.

Answer (score 0):

Если `on_next_page_clicked` это слот и если где-то (например в конструкторе класса theory - наследнике по цепочке от QObject) есть такая строка:

```
connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &theory::on_next_page_clicked);
```

здесь `pushButton` это указатель на `QPushButton*`

Тогда так:

```
void theory::on_next_page_clicked()
{
    static int index = -1;
    
    index = ++index % pages.count();

    ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(pages[index] + " ");
}
```